# compute volume of transformed bodies

Tags: math, matrix, transformation

So I want to compute the volume of spheres (unit balls), cuboids (cubes) that are transformed using arbitrary transformation matrices.

e.g.: I got my Sphere with a radius of 1 in the center of my 3D-Space. Then i got a Transformation to apply to that Sphere. What would the volume (resp. radius) be after that? How can i extract that information from the Transformation Matrix? I know that translation and rotation matrices wont affect that, but scaling matrices will.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

The transformation's determinant specifies how the volume of any object changes. If the determinant is 1, the volume is preserved. If it is negative, there is a mirroring included which results in a reversed face order.

Only use the linear part of the matrix to calculate the determinant (disregarding translations and perspective transformations).

Another measure that you might be interested in are the matrice's eigen values and eigen vectors (or singular values). They specify the orientation of the ellipsoid that a matrix transforms a unit sphere into.

Answer (score 0):

If the transformation is a [rigid motion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RigidMotion.html), then the mass is unaffected by the transform.  If the transform is the composition of a rigid motion and a uniform scaling, then the volume is multiplied by the cube of the scale factor.

That is, if S is a homogeneous scaling transform in the form:

```
    [ s 0 0 0 ]
    [ 0 s 0 0 ]
S = [ 0 0 s 0 ]
    [ 0 0 0 1 ]
```

and R is a rigid homogeneous transform, then the mass m of a body transformed by S.R or R.S is m*s^3.

Other than these two special cases (rigid motion and uniform scaled motion), and ignoring trivial cases such as the case where the transform maps all points to a plane, there is no simple formula for the transformed volumes.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, Right, cubed.  Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

**OpenGL transform matrix is stored like this:**

```
double m[16]; // it is 4x4 matrix stored as 1 dimensional array for speed
m[0]=xx; m[4]=yx; m[ 8]=zx; m[12]=x0;
m[1]=xy; m[5]=yy; m[ 9]=zy; m[13]=y0;
m[2]=xz; m[6]=yz; m[10]=zz; m[14]=z0;
m[3]= 0; m[7]= 0; m[11]= 0; m[15]= 1;
```

- where:
- X(xx,xy,xz) is unit vector of X axis in GCS (global coordinate system)
- Y(yx,yy,yz) is unit vector of Y axis in GCS
- Z(zx,zy,zz) is unit vector of Z axis in GCS
- P(x0,y0,z0) is origin of represented coordinate system in GCS

**when orthogonal transforms are applied (rotation,translation,scale...)**

- then shape is 'preserved'
- cube became cuboid and sphere became ellipsoid
- then the size of axises vector is the scale in that axis
- so if Volume of object before transformation is V0
- then Volume after transform is:

  ```
  V1=V0*|X|*|Y|*|Z|
  ```

**when non orthogonal transforms are applied (skew,projections,...)**

- **skew** is one of the non-orthogonal but linear transforms
- Volume can be computed as for orthogonal transforms
- but the shape will be broken.
- because non orthogonal transforms change
- not only size but the shape itself !!!
- non-linear transforms like projections always broke the Volume nonlinearly
- in this case you have to compute the Volume the hard way
- transform object surface and compute the Volume via integration ...

**How to determine orthogonality of transform?**

- easy transforms are orthogonal if X,Y,Z vectors are perpendicular
- to each other then transform is linear so:

  ```
  XY = X x Y; XY /= |XY|; Z0=Z/|Z|;
  XZ = X x Z; XZ /= |XZ|; Y0=Y/|Y|;
  YZ = Y x Z; YZ /= |YZ|; X0=X/|X|;

  if ((XY!=Z0)&&(XY!=-Z0)) non linear;
  if ((XZ!=Y0)&&(XZ!=-Y0)) non linear;
  if ((YZ!=X0)&&(YZ!=-X0)) non linear;
  ```
- do not forget to do the comparisons with some accuracy
- to avoid FP problems

**How to detect non linearity of transform?**

- create a set of points evenly placed inside some cube (same distance between them)
- transform them
- now if the point distances are not the same along new axises
- but change with distance from origin then transform is non-linear

Comment: Skewing is a linear transformation. Linearity doesn't have to do with orthogonality.

Comment: (+1) in that case the Volume is computed as linear transform (just check few images and your\e right) ... but the orthogonality test will not pass I will edit shortly

Comment: @NicoSchertler Done, I messed it up orthogonality preserves Shape and Linearity preserves Volume not the other way around thx for point it out

Comment: It's still not correct. A simple skew operation does not change the volume. Yet, one of the principal axes becomes longer (or shorter), so according to you, it would have a different volume. Linearity does not necessarily preserve volume. Scaling is a linear transform and it obviously does change the volume. Detecting linearity is just done by comparing the last row and last column to `(0, 0, 0, 1)`. What's the `*` in your orthogonality detection? Orthogonality can be detected by comparing the dot product of two principle vectors to 0.

Comment: @NicoSchertler operator * is vector and standard multiplications (vector multiplication if it is between vectors and scalar if it is between scalar and vector or scalar and scalar). sorry for the preserve it should be in 'preserve' (I know it is not always the same just scaled by some scalar). The dot product is easier dint think of that :) (I usually use the unit vectors for orthogonality repairs of an matrix so I am used to use them instead). Mine linear algebra is rusty (use geometric representation) does the last row linearity check apply on all non linear transforms or just projections?

Comment: All linear transforms are in the upper left 3x3 matrix. Perspective transforms are in the last row, translations are in the last column. So if there is nothing in the last row and nothing in the last column, the transform is linear (i.e. `f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)`). What vector multiplication do you mean? There are several ones - cross product, dot product, componentwise...

Comment: @NicoSchertler cross product of coarse but yes you;re right it is not didactic to leave * instead of x (for those who can not see vector = vector * vector as cross product at first look ... to obtain perpendicular vector) in mine language is only one vector multiplication others have very different names